# Create a select in template from list

Tags: django

Hi everyone I have this in my template

```
  {% with 'By Visit, By Patient' as list %}
    <div class="selector_healthApp">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="sel1">Select Categoty:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="item_project">
              {% for cat_name in list.split %}
                <option>{{ cat_name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endwith %}
{% endblock content %}
```

I have a list and I want to show each item of list in a select

if I used `{% for cat_name in list.split %}` I have 4 element in the select

```
By
Visit
By 
Patient
```

id I use `{% for cat_name in list %}` it is separate by characters

How to do this to show in the select  'By Visit' and 'By Patient'

Why if I try in the terminal this works

```
list = [By Visit, By Patient]
>>> for iten in list:
...     print iten
... 
By Visit
By Patient
>>>
```

Thanks in advances

Comment: Don't do this. Send the values, as a list, from the view. Even better, use a proper form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use *list.split* it will split on **space** that's causing issue.

And Django doesn't provide split template tag so you cannot pass argument  on split (i.e. split on **","**).

You can write your own custom template tag, Read from here, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/

Template Tag:

```
from django.template.defaulttags import register


@register.filter()
def split(value, arg):
    return value.split(arg)
```

Template:

```
{% load split %}
  {% with 'By Visit, By Patient'|split:"," as list %}
    <div class="selector_healthApp">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label for="sel1">Select Categoty:</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="item_project">
              {% for cat_name in list %}
                <option>{{ cat_name }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endwith %}
```